# How to merge 4 unsigned char array elements in one hex value?

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux

I have an array of 4 elements of type unsigned char. How to merge these in one hex value? I need to convert this value to IEE754 value.

e.g. `unsigned char arr[]={0x41,0xD9,0xD4,0x03}`

expected o/p : `0x41D9D403`

Comment: The problem with multi-byte types is the byte ordering. Once you've fixed that it's a simple [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) call. Or, since you use C, you can use a `union` for [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning).

Comment: Is this the byte ordering you are talking about. Pls suggest.      
  unsigned char result;                                                                        
 result = arr[0]<<24 | arr[1]<<16 | arr[2]<<8 | arr[3]

Comment: There is no such thing as a _"hex value"_; you eothet mean a _hex string_ representation of an integer value, or more likely in this case simply a 32-bit integer.  Hexadecimal is merely a human readable representation of an integer value; normally used for presentation or ASCII encoding of data not for internal representation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, you should not use memcpy or union (or pointer arithmetic), because those are endianess dependent. The correct solution is to use portable bit shifts, everything else is wrong.

Comment: @Lundin `memcpy` or unions are fine once the byte ordering problem have been solved. Maybe I was a little vague about that in my comment. And `memcpy` from `char` arrays or unions are the only way to do type-punning without breaking strict aliasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned long hex_val = ((unsigned long)arr[0] << 24) | ((unsigned long)arr[1] << 16) | ((unsigned long)arr[2] << 8) | ((unsigned long)arr[3]);
```

Comment: On a 32 bit system, this invokes undefined behavior for `arr[0] >= 0x80`. The correct code casts each operand to `unsigned long` before shifting. Please correct the example.

Comment: @Lundin - Is the undefined behavior because of the following reason ? 1) arr[0] is `unsigned char` and is promoted to `int` during the shift operation. 2) Let's consider a system on which `sizeof(int) == 2` and `arr[0] >= 0x80`. 3) If we shift by 8 places i.e. `arr[0] << 8`, then the sign bit is set which is not what we expected since `arr[0]` is `unsigned char`.

Comment: Indeed! In case of a 32 bit computer, then the 0x80 << 24 shifts data into the sign bit of the temporary variable, which contains the unsigned char's data, silently promoted to `int`.